# How can I get variable to text from php to swift app

Tags: swift

I use this code and work perfect. I use swift. PHP is work fine.
I also try some other examples at this 
I have 2 problems 
first my responseString values turns in Optional("Success"). Why?
second is How can assign it on my button?

```
func makePostCall() {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "MyURL/page.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "id=login"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")

            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            self.lbl.text = responseString
        }
        task.resume()
        //return responseString

    }
```

Comment: I am ok with editing optional. I write -- var txtOut = responseString as! String -- it is ok. but other condition is still not solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `DispatchQueue.main.async` to work with UI from `URLRequests`. Also you need to use `[weak self]` to prevent `reference cycle` problem. At last, `btn.setTitle(responseString, for: .normal)` to set title for button state `.normal`. Here is correct answer!

```
func makePostCall() {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "MyURL/page.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "id=login"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {[weak self] data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")

            }

            guard let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                  return
            }
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.lbl.text = responseString
                self?.btn.setTitle(responseString, for: .normal) // your button
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        //return responseString

    }
```

Comment: Can you check it as an answer?

Comment: Sorry I have only 2 answers. I am like newbee. Thanks again